# Error '403 disallowed_useragent' logging to google via angularfire on a mobile browser

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am developing a project with angularfire2 v4.0.0-rc.2 in angular4 and publishing it on firebase.

The logins with facebook and google are both working on the desktop browser and on a native android app.

When I try to login within chrome via mobile browser, I got the following error:
[image]

I've found many post about google blocking the access by webViews but none give a really answer about how to fix the problem without workarounds not specific to firebase.

The error occurs either using angularfire signIn with popup and redirect.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I just realized that installing another browser (chrome for instance), the login 
 with google get back to work... Maybe a possible work around could be make a list of blocked user-agents and display a message to the users asking to change browser... anyway, it seems dirty =\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am having a similar issue with Google Login (and Facebook Login actually).

Specifically, when someone shares a link within the Facebook Messenger Application (iOS AND Android) and the link is clicked using the in-app browser, I get the same 403 error.

The best workaround I have found for this is to detect the user agent (`navigator.userAgent`) and see whether it includes 'Messenger' in the string and then show a message to ask them to open in their normal browser.

It would be much better if there was a way for these in-app browsers that have this problem to either just work, or to have a way to open in a normal browser without the user needing to find that functionality.

```
if (window.navigator.userAgent.includes('Messenger')) {
  console.log('User agent includes Messenger');
} else {
  console.log('User agent does not include Messenger');
}
```